# On calculating the mean R-Squared score of K-Fold CV in Sci-kit

Tags: python, k-fold

I've done DecisionTreeRegression as well as RandomForestRegression on the same dataset.

For RandomForest I've used 5 random best combinations and the results were all similar results as you'd expect. I've calculated the average of R^2, RMSE and MAE and have gotten
R^2 : 0.7, MAE: 145716, RMSE: 251828.

For DecisionTree I've used Repeated K-Fold, calculated the average and gotten:
R^2: 0.29, MAE: 121791, RMSE: 198280.

No transformations or scaling have been done on the response variable which is Home Prices.

I'm new to statistics, but I'm pretty sure R^2 should be higher, if MAE and RMSE are lower on the same dataset when there is no scaling done. That being said, the dataset in question is pretty low in quality compared to the other datasets that I'm using which are yielding the appropriate proportions in error scores.

My question is, since this dataset is poor in quality, and I'm sure that there will be negative R2 values as well as above one for the DecisionTree Model for this dataset: Is it possible that calculating the mean of scores after cross-validation gives arbitrary results for R^2, if some of the R^2 values are not in the 0-1 interval, or is it more likely that there's an issue with the logic of my code(or something else)?

```py
def decisionTreeRegression(df, features):
    df = df.sample(frac=1, random_state=0)
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    
    X = df[features]
    y = df[['Price']]

    param_grid = {'max_depth': np.arange(1,40,3)}
    tree = GridSearchCV(DecisionTreeRegressor(), param_grid,return_train_score=False)
    tree.fit(X,y)
    tree_final = DecisionTreeRegressor(max_depth=tree.best_params_['max_depth'])
    cv = RepeatedKFold(n_splits=5, n_repeats=100)
    mae_scores = cross_val_score(tree_final, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    mse_scores = cross_val_score(tree_final, X, y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
    r2_scores = cross_val_score(tree_final, X, y, scoring='r2', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
        
    return makeScoresCV(mae_scores,mse_scores,r2_scores)
```

```py
def makeScoresCV(mae_scores,mse_scores,r2_scores):
    # convert scores to positive
    mae_scores= absolute(mae_scores)
    mse_scores= absolute(mse_scores)
    # summarize the result
    s_mean = mean(mae_scores)
    s_mean2 = mean(mse_scores)
    s_mean3 = mean(r2_scores)
    return s_mean,np.sqrt(s_mean2),s_mean3

mae, rmse, r2 = decisionTreeRegression(df_de,fe_de)
print("mae : " + str(mae))
print("rmse : " + str(rmse))
print("r2 : " + str(r2))

Console:
mae : 153189.34673362423
rmse : 253284.5137707182
r2 : 0.30183525616923246
```

Random Forest (seperate notebook):

```py
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = df.drop('Price', axis = 1)
y = df['Price']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,test_size=0.2, random_state=123, shuffle=True)

scaler.fit(X_train)
X_train = scaler.transform(X_train)
X_test = scaler.transform(X_test)



def evaluate(model, test_features, test_labels):
    predictions = model.predict(test_features)
    rmse = (np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(test_labels,predictions)))
    r2 = r2_score(test_labels,predictions) # from sklearn.metrics
    mae = np.sum(np.absolute((test_labels - predictions))) / len(predictions)

    return mae,r2,rmse

maes = []
rmses = []
r2s = []
for i in range(10):
   rf_random.fit(X_train, y_train)
   best_random = rf_random.best_estimator_
   mae,r2,rmse = evaluate(best_random, X_test, y_test)
   maes.append(mae)
   rmses.append(rmse)
   r2s.append(r2)

print("MAE")
print(math.fsum(maes) / len(maes))
print("RMSE")
print(math.fsum(rmses) / len(rmses))
print("R2")
print(math.fsum(r2s) / len(r2s))


Console:
MAE
145716.7264983288
RMSE
251828.40328030512
R2
0.7082730127977784
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Rsquared is basically 1 - the square of your residuals divided by the variance.. its the same response variable, so if r-squared goes down, RMSE must increase. can you share the code and data to reproduce this amazing finding?

Comment: Thanks for your interest in my post, I'm not sure in what form I can share the data. Is there a certain type of plot that might be useful to add?

Comment: It's not a public dataset unfortunately

Comment: Try your code on a public dataset like Boston. You will see that you are doing scaling separately so the results are not comparable.

Comment: You need to do the evaluation on the same train test split

Comment: Okay, I've actually checked the results list for the decision tree regression and there is no R^2 above 1, however min(r2_scores) gives me a really low value around -3.

Comment: issue resolved, that was it, thanks